# laravel no wait return page

Tags: laravel, view, stream, response

May i set laravel not wait for return page

example.

i import 1 millan rows from textfile
and need show sample import data to user every 1000 row

now laravel cache response and return one time.

may i write laravel flush html many time?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LargeImportController extends Controller
{
    ....
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
            echo view('store_header', [
                'columns' => $this->columns,
                'import_id' => $import_id,
                'title' => 'CollectionFees',
            ]);
           ....
           loop import data

            echo some sample data every 1000 record

           ....

            echo view('store_footer', [
                'columns' => $this->columns,
                'import_id' => $import_id,
                'title' => 'CollectionFees',
            ]);
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data every 1000 records from one request. Since a request can only have one response.

You could import the text file and process it in a queue return a view that has JavaScript that sends a new request every x seconds and shows for example how many records are already recorded. This way, you can show how many records are saved and this will drastically improve user satisfaction.